# How to create a C# application that opens "cmd.exe" in another window?

Tags: c#, cmd, process, subprocess, processstartinfo

**What I'd like to Do**

I'd like to create a simple C# application that creates a `Process` object (the application's child process) that runs `cmd.exe` and, inside that shell, execute the command `echo "Hello World!"` (or whatever arbitrary string I specified before compiling the application). The C# application, when built and ran, creates and leave the shell in this state:

[image: Desired Window]

**Attempts**

I've searched stackoverflow and MSDN for examples but it's difficult to find the right options to set for `Process`, `ProcessStartInfo`. In particular, I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "echo helloworld!";
            string strCmdText;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            */


            var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = @"cmd.exe", // iexplorer.exe opened up ie!
                    Arguments = "",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\mtran\Desktop\ConsoleApp1", 
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal

                }
            };
            proc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

but either second cmd window (for the child process) never appears (if I set `RedirectStandardOutput = false`)or the output of from the child process gets written to the parent's cmd window.

Comment: Do you want the new CMD window to stay open **after** your program ends?

Comment: @JuanR Yes. The CMD window for the subprocess should stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k ECHO hello Juan!");
```

It will launch the command window, execute the `ECHO` statement and keep the window open.

Feel free to use a `ProcessStartInfo` instance as the parameter if you need additional configuration.

If you run `cmd /?` on a command prompt, you can see additional information about the switches:

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then
>   terminates
>
> /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

Comment: Aha! I ran a SO solution earlier containing a similar call with `arguments` field value containing `/c` flag but the comment didn't explain that it meant 'close the window` (so I saw the window appear and then quickly disappear). 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2

Seems to explain it better but `/c` and `/k` flags aren't documented. `/c` is short for 'close' and `/k` for 'keep-open' perhaps? 

Thanks so much!

Comment: @MinhTran: Ha! I will edit my answer to clarify that for others. You're welcome!